# Find the total number of emails in a folder (with all of the subfolders)

Tags: beginner, recursion, go

The Folder struct definition below is given:

```
type Folder struct { 
    ID int
    emailCount int
    childFolderIDs []int
}
```

Description of the fields are:

- `Id`                 : folder id
- `emailCount`         : number of emails in the folder
- `childFolderIDS`     : if the folder has subfolders, this list contains folder IDS of the subfolders.

I am trying to write a function:

- Function is taking two parameters:

  - First parameter is a list of all folders in the email application

    ```golang
      var folders = []Folder{  
            Folder{1, 30, []int{2, 4}},  
            Folder{2, 10, []int{3}},  
            Folder{4, 60, []int{}},  
            Folder{3, 20, []int{}},  
      }
    ```
  - Second parameter is folder id of a folder
- Function will return a total number of emails with ID=Folder Id and all of its children recursively.

For example:

If the second parameter is:

- **four**, then the function should return **60** (there is no subfolder)
- **two**, then the function should return **30**

My code is below:

````golang
      package main

      import "fmt"

      type Folder struct {
          ID int
          emailCount int
          childFolderIDs []int
      }

      func InsertIntoMap(data_arr []Folder) map[int]Folder {
          var retval = make(map[int]Folder)
          var child_folders []int
          for _, elem := range data_arr {
            child_folders = elem.childFolderIDs
            var folder Folder 
            folder.ID = elem.ID
            folder.emailCount = elem.emailCount
            folder.childFolderIDs = child_folders
            retval[elem.ID] = folder
          }    

          return retval
      }

    func GetTotalEmailCount(p_map map[int]Folder, folder_id int) int {
          total := 0
          var child_folders []int
          child_folders = p_map[folder_id].childFolderIDs
          total = total + p_map[folder_id].emailCount

          if len(child_folders) == 0{
            return total
          }else{
            for e := range child_folders {
              return total + GetTotalEmailCount(p_map, child_folders[e])
              }          
          }

          return total
    }

      func main() {

        var folders = []Folder{
          Folder{1, 30, []int{2, 4}},
          Folder{2, 10, []int{3}},
          Folder{4, 60, []int{}},
          Folder{3, 20, []int{}},
      }

      var m = InsertIntoMap(folders)

      fmt.Println(GetTotalEmailCount(m,1))  // result is 60
      fmt.Println(GetTotalEmailCount(m,2))  // result is 30
      fmt.Println(GetTotalEmailCount(m,3))  // result is 20
      fmt.Println(GetTotalEmailCount(m,4))  // result is 60

      }
```
````

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. The indentation of your code is inconsistent, and part of your example (`Second parameter is:`) ended up in a code block. You may want to fix this before reviewing starts. (Code in the question shall stay unchanged conce you got answers. Or serious time passed since asking (- 24 hours?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code doesn't give correnct answers; for `(m, 1)` the answer should be 120 (30 in `./1`, +10 in `./1/2`, +20 in `./1/2/3`, +60 in `./1/4`; you never count more than a single entry in the sub-folder slice).

Also, you should run `go fmt` (or [`goimports`](https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports)) on your code (perhaps you did and that was lost when posting). Also, adding a [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/web83IsUyly) link to your original code in posts is helpful.

You mention that you wanted to create a function taking two parameters, the first being `[]Folder` but your code instead converts the slice into a map and uses that as the first argument. Which did you intend? When you have a function or functions that are answering questions based on an argument you could consider making a method. For example, perhaps something like:

```golang
type Folders []Folder
// or
type Folders struct {
    list []Folder
    byID map[int]Folder
}

func (f Folders) EMailCount(folder int) int {
    // code that uses f and folder as arguments
}
```

You use `snake_case` for some of your identifiers and `camelCase` for others; idiomatic Go code uses `camelCase` for all identifiers.

In your `InsertIntoMap` function:

- When you `make` the map you know how many entries you expect so you should include that number to make as a size hint (e.g. `make(map[int]Folder, len(data))`). If the size is large this avoids the having to dynamically re-size the map as you add entries.
- You name the map `retval`, I'd instead name it based on what contains (a map of folders by ID) rather than it happens to be the return value. I'd call it just `m` or `byID`.
- Within the loop you effectively copy the element `elem` to the variable `folder`. You can do this with just `folder := elem` but at that point the entire loop body can just be rewritten as `retval[elem.ID] = elem`.

In your `GetTotalEmailCount` function:

- Normally in Go instead of:

  ```
  var foo []int
  foo = something[bar].foo
  ```

  you'll just see:

  ```
  foo := something[bar].foo
  ```

  not only is it shorter but it can make future code changes easier. In the latter if the field `foo` changes type you don't need to edit the type of the variable `foo` to match. (By the way, shorter isn't always better. Clarity is more important than conciseness).
- Idiomatic Go code tends avoid indenting code by using early returns (see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#indent-error-flow). You return if `len(…) == 0` so you should just drop the `else` clause and remove the indent ([`golint`](https://golang.org/x/lint/golint) will suggest this). E.g, instead of:

  ```
  if someCondition {
      return something
  } else {
      // other code
      //     possibly with more conditional/loop indenting
  }
  ```

  it would be:

  ```
  if someCondition {
      return something
  }

  // other code
  //     possibly with more conditional/loop indenting
  ```
- In this specific case, you don't even need the conditional since `for range` loops don't do anything on empty/nil slices the following `return total` line is sufficient.
- It's in this `for` loop your your bug exists. On the first iteration you stop looping and return the total of this folder and it's first child without iterating to the next child.

  ```
  return total + GetTotalEmailCount(p_map, child_folders[e])
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  total += GetTotalEmailCount(p_map, child_folders[e])
  ```

Without changing the basic structure of your code, all the above gives something like this ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_SLPYNTOwcu)):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Folder struct {
    ID             int
    emailCount     int
    childFolderIDs []int
}

func InsertIntoMap(data []Folder) map[int]Folder {
    m := make(map[int]Folder, len(data))
    for _, e := range data {
        m[e.ID] = e
    }
    return m
}

func GetTotalEmailCount(m map[int]Folder, folder int) int {
    children := m[folder].childFolderIDs
    total := m[folder].emailCount

    for e := range children {
        // BUG: doesn't detect infinite loops
        total += GetTotalEmailCount(m, children[e])
    }

    return total
}

func main() {
    var folders = []Folder{
        Folder{1, 30, []int{2, 4}},
        Folder{2, 10, []int{3}},
        Folder{4, 60, []int{}},
        Folder{3, 20, []int{}},
    }

    var m = InsertIntoMap(folders)
    fmt.Println(GetTotalEmailCount(m, 1)) // result is 120, 30+10+20+60
    fmt.Println(GetTotalEmailCount(m, 2)) // result is 30
    fmt.Println(GetTotalEmailCount(m, 3)) // result is 20
    fmt.Println(GetTotalEmailCount(m, 4)) // result is 60
}
```

Comment: This was my first Go code. Thank you for your valuable comments.